# Working with/on/under a visa?

Tags: grammar

I'm looking for a new job and want to let the recruiters know that my current employer issued a visa that allows me to work in the US. So which sentence should I use?

I'm working **on** a H1 visa

I'm working **under** a H1 visa

I'm working **with** a H1 visa

Comment: *Working ON a(n) H1 visa* would be correct,

Comment: @RonaldSole Be careful because that can be confused with "I don't have a visa but am *working on it*" whereas I would just say "I have an H1b visa."

Comment: @TsSkTo Fair comment!

Comment: @TsSkTo True, although context often solves it. E.g. it's common to say "He's in the US *on* an H1 visa".

Comment: Not related to the question, but the correct article is *an*, not *a*, since the pronunciation of /H/ begins with a vowel sound.